ASP.NET NormalizedUsername changes on update User data
I'm developing an asp.net app and i run into the issue while setting up 2FA. After enabling this, a field on the database updated to True and the NormalizedUsername changed with it. Originally this value was the the same as the email but in uppercase, once it updated it changed to match the username in uppercase.
In practice, this makes perfect sense, after all they're both username related fields. But when I try to log in after that change, I get an "Invalid login attempt" error, and if I change the NormalizedUsername back to its original value, I can log in back again.
The login asks for the user's email and not its username.
I noticed this to happen whenever I update user data through the scaffolded view on the running application.
This is part of my custom User class. The remaining fields are identity's defaults:
namespace Project.Areas.Identity.Data;

public class USUARIO : IdentityUser
{
    [PersonalData]
    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(100)")]
    public string? NOMBRE { get; set; }

    [PersonalData]
    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(100)")]
    public string? APELLIDO { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.ImageUrl)]
    public string? AVATAR { get; set; }
}

An the database looks like this after data update



UserName
NormalizedUserName
Email
NormalizedEmail




edwin
TEST2@EXAMPLE.NET
test2@example.net
TEST2@EXAMPLE.NET


trisha
TRISHA
test3@example.net
TEST3@EXAMPLE.NET



In this instance the user trisha can no longer log in, neither with the email, NormalizedUsername nor Username unless the NormalizedUsername is changed back to match the uppercased email.
The columns changed through the view do update the corresponding column on the database as expected, but this issue with the NormalizedUsername makes no sense to me.
As I said, I'm kinda new to this framework, only working on it for about 2 months now and the identity user I have has custom fields, so I'm not entirely aware of what I might've missed in its configuration.
Any help or suggestion would be much appreciated.
OnPostAsync method:
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
{
    returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");

    ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Convertir el correo electrónico a mayúsculas
        var email = Input.Email.ToUpper();

        // Realizar el inicio de sesión utilizando el correo electrónico convertido a mayúsculas
        var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
            return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
        }
        if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
        {
            return RedirectToPage("./LoginWith2fa", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = Input.RememberMe });
        }
        if (result.IsLockedOut)
        {
            _logger.LogWarning("User account locked out.");
            return RedirectToPage("./Lockout");
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
            return Page();
        }
    }
    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return Page();
}


Why not use .ToUpper() when you are gathering the email from the login form and then match it in the database?

@RahulSharma so what you're saying is that, in the login form i should compare the Email to the NormalizedEmail? Because I have a feeling that right now its doing the comparison between Email and NormalizedUserName, that would explain why I'm getting the invalid login attempt message...
I did minor changes to the Login.cshtml.cs to specify that it must use USUARIO class, but i havent changed the lines from the methods it uses.

I am not sure how you are doing the comparison? Are you using SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync ? Or are you doing the authentication using your own custom logic? You need to show that in your question.

@RahulSharma sorry, i updated the question with the method. But I've barely done any changes to it, so its pretty standard. I tried the ToUpper method you suggested but still nothing.

Well since in your case the username != email, you should first retrieve the email of the user: ApplicationUser foundUser= UserManager.FindByEmail(Input.Email); and once you have the information, then use PasswordSignInAsync:  var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(foundUser.Username, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false); Please note that you should check that signedUser is not null. Otherwise that will throw an exception

In your case since the username != email,  you should first retrieve the email of the user:
ApplicationUser foundUser= UserManager.FindByEmail(Input.Email);

Once you have the user, then use
var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(foundUser.Username, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);

Please note that you should check that foundUser is not null. Otherwise that will throw an exception
